# Debugging new Mozilla WebExtension API

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon-webextensions

I am trying to port a `Chrome` extension to `Firefox` using the new Mozilla [WebExtension API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions). The problem is that using `Chrome` I could debug the background page and the popup separately. Moreover, the *popup.js* script was run everytime the popup was opened, and the *background.js* could be reloaded using <kbd>Ctrl+R</kbd>… and I have no idea how to do this in `Firefox`. I don't even know if it's possible. As far as I have seen, both scripts (*background.js* and *popup.js*) are executed only when the browser is restarted (aren't they?).

Anyone knows how to solve these issues, or a good way to debug Firefox extensions written with the `WebExtension API`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recent versions of Firefox (e.g. 49) have more capable WebExtension debugging tools, and [recent docs on MDN explain how to use them](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Debugging). You'll want [the Browser Toolbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Browser_Toolbox), and you may want to [set up a custom Firefox profile](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profile-manager-create-and-remove-firefox-profiles) that enables the Browser Toolbox by default (or has installed the [DevPrefs addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/devprefs/)).

Comment: DevPrefs addon seems to be abandoned -- any current answers?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately debugging WebExtensions is a pain at the moment. A [related bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1185464).

The only thing you can do at this time is use `debugger;` statements to set the breakpoints in the code. The debugger you need is [Browser Toolbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Browser_Toolbox).

Open the Browser Toolbox, focus the debugger tab, wait for the sources to load and then trigger your code to reach those statements. Proceed as usual.

As for reloading things, browser action was [supposedly fixed](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1190662) and the background is executed every time you disable and re-enable your addon.

However, Firefox suffers from various [code cache issues](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1051238) since forever so disabling and re-enabling your addon might not pick up any changes. Your best bet is restarting the browser every time. There is also a [discussion to support live reload](https://mail.mozilla.org/pipermail/dev-addons/2015-December/000234.html).

Answer (score 1):

Did you tryed with the Browser Toolbox? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Browser_Toolbox

Once your Firefox has the  "Enable browser chrome and add-on debugging toolboxes" and "Enable remote debugging" options enabled, you can access it with Ctrl + Alt +Shift + I key combination.